# Scrollview is not scrolling inside a custom view for a listview

Tags: android, scrollview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"

        >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/prayerMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="please God forgive me for all my mistakes i have ever done in my life please God forgive me for all my mistakes i have ever"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"

            />

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my xml file and scrollview is not scrolling.

Can anyone please suggest a solution?

I am using a custom view for a listview using a custom adapter

Comment: which xml file is given here? ListView item?

Comment: It seems like this is the ListView item... the suggestion is to not use ScrollViews inside ListViews as it pretty much defeats the purpose of the ListView... There are many posts about that on StackOverflow and on the internet in general. There are also multiple other errors in the layout: the RelativeLayout has a set height which has smaller size than the scrollview. But even in case you do it you won't see the results because of nested scrolling containers which do not support nested scrolling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not recommended to use multiple Scrollable view inside one another. You are using ScrollView inside List View and that you should not do. It is a bad practice.

Instead you use Dynamic Layout Addition via
view.add()

Answer (score 1):

Height of your scroll view is 200dp. Since 200dp fits in the screen there is nothing to scroll. You can try setting the height to

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

or

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

if height of your UI items are larger then screen size.